# simulator folder cannot be found XCode 6.1

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6.1

Simulators work fine but I cannot find the folder where they are stored. I looked all over my mac.

In Library\Application Support\iPhone Simulator\ found only old simulators folders from previous XCode 5.

Any clues? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

hoo hoo, I found it, all simulators are in

Library\Application Support\Developer\CoreSimulator\Devices\YOU_SIM_IDs
[image]

and apps are further down in

YOUR_SIM_ID\data\Containers\Data\Application\YOUR_APP_ID

[image]